# YUI3 shifter change build directory

Tags: javascript, build, yui

I am fairly new to YUI3 and shifter builder, if there is any ways to configurate build output directory over there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shifter configuration file add

```
"build-dir": "js/build"
```

or pass `--build-dir=js/build` to shifter on the command line.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, that's was easy, wonder why it is not reflected into documentation.

Comment: I asked myself the very same thing. I had to check the code. And you're welcome!